# regex in zf2 routing

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework2

Hi I am trying to pass a regex expression in zf2 routing, My router looks like this :

```
    'exampleroute' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(

                    'route'    => '/exampleroute/[:regexparameter]',
                    'constraints' => array(

                             'regexparameter' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-][$.]*',

                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(

                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Mynamespace\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'exampleroute',
                            'action'        => 'example',
                    ),
            ),
    ),
```

I want to pass the following URL: `http://mydomain.com/exampleroute/$2y$14$aPW5u7oGpuuMPRKRz6la1.m2SpJ2STFJ9BZ7giSwfKQxWKIuTODmW`

but it gives me an error of "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

Comment: `action` constraint is excess? You have only `regexparameter`

Answer (score 2):

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-][$.]*` means:

1. First symbol must be `a-zA-Z`
2. Second symbol must be `a-zA-Z0-9_-`
3. Followed by any number of `$` or `.` symbols

I guess you need this:

`[a-zA-Z0-9_-$.]*`

Comment: @mishik, @user2055227 What do you think of escaping dollar and the hyphen symbol ? Like `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\$.]*`

Comment: This is not needed inside `[]`. `/^[.]$/` will match _only_ `.`

Answer (score 0):

Its Working like this now:

```
'exampleroute' => array(
        'type'    => 'segment',
        'options' => array(

                'route'    => '/exampleroute/[:regexparameter]',
                'constraints' => array(

                         'regexparameter' => '[$.a-zA-z0-9_-]*',

                ),
                'defaults' => array(

                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Mynamespace\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'exampleroute',
                        'action'        => 'example',
                ),
        ),
),
```

Comment: Hm, so you are saying that `[a-zA-Z0-9_-$.]*` does not work and `[$.a-zA-z0-9_-]*` does work?